# How to use generic method of non generic interface in a client class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a non-generic interface with a method of generic return type.

```
public interface IReport
{
    List<T> GenerateReport<T>();
}
```

How can I implement this method in my client class? I tried below methods. All are showing error.
Method 1:

```
public class Report : IReport
{
    public List<T> GenerateReport<T>()
    {
        return new List<ReportModel>(){ new ReportModel { Name="Report1" } };
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
public class Report : IReport
{
    public List<ReportModel> GenerateReport<ReportModel>()
    {
        return new List<ReportModel>(){ new ReportModel { Name="Report1" } };
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 1: Does not work since your return type is a `List<T>` but you return a `List<ReportModel>` and `T` may not be a `ReportModel`. Method 2: Won't work since you return a `List<ReportModel>` but the interface specifies you should return a `List<T>`. You can add generic constraints in your interface but I don't think you are approaching the problem correctly.

Comment: While the is not an exact duplicate, the answers are the same. Long story short, what you are attempting to do can't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not like that.

Your `IReport` interface promises that you have a method `GenerateReport` which can take *any* type of report, and will generate it.

Your `Report` class only promises to be able to generate `ReportModels` - it can't generate *any* type of report.

If I had a variable of type `IReport`, I would expect to be able to ask it to generate any type of report, for example:

```
IReport report = ...
report.GenerateReport<ReportModel>();
report.GenerateReport<OtherReportModel>();
```

Your `Report` class can't do that - it can only generate reports containing `ReportModel`, so you're breaking the contract in your interface.

What you probably wanted to do is to make the whole `IReport` interface generic:

```
public interface IReport<T>
{
    List<T> GenerateReport();
}
```

Then your `Report` class can implement `IReport<ReportModel>`. This means that it promises to generate reports containing `ReportModel`, and no other type of report:

```
public class Report : IReport<ReportModel>
{
    public List<ReportModel> GenerateReport()
    {
        return new List<ReportModel>(){ new ReportModel { Name="Report1" } };
    }
}
```